Spoof movie where character comes out of sewer into 1990 Ninja Turtles movie
All I can remember about this movie is that one of the characters was coming up through a sewer tunnel and ended up in The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (1990) movie during the scene where the turtles are playing a board game at the farm house. I'm also pretty sure that the character comes up in other populat movies as well and was looking for something or running from someome in the spoof movie. This movie was live action, made in the US or Canada, and could have been made anytime between 1991 and 2005. 

This was National Lampoon's Loaded Weapon 1, from 1993.
TV Tropes uses this as an example of Stock Footage:

Colt (Emilio Estevez) enters the sewers to make it on the other side of a fence to the villain's warehouse. Before finding the right exit manhole, he comes across a room which houses the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles playing Trivial Pursuit, which is footage from the 1990 film.


Beat me to it. It's also mentioned in the "Featured In" section of the Connections page of the IMDb listing for the movie (that OP listed above).

Thanks, that probably would've been an easier way to find it. I'll have to remember that.

I looked at the connections page of IMDB before posting. I guess I overlooked it. Thanks!
